# How to import a shared proto file in different packages?

Tags: import, protocol-buffers

`import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";`

For the above import statement, I wonder how protoc knows where to find that proto file, since it's obviously not in somewhere of my `proto_path`.

I have a `shared.proto` in some package, and could be refered by many projects, so I cannot put it to some project level to share the same protp_path. My question is how to refer this proto just like import `duration.proto`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question for me because I know why it works but (still) don't fully understand how.

Why? Because the [well-known types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf) are bundled with `protoc` in a `lib` folder alongside the `bin` folder. I assume for e.g. Python, the implementation similarly includes these.

How? I think (!?) this works because `protoc` is configured (!?) to look for these types in that location (where is `protoc`? Look for `lib` in a sibling folder).

The documentation would benefit from explaining this because I used to manually add these to `proto_path` until once, when I didn't and worked without the import.